# How add column BY to a query?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

How do I include the column BY in a query?
I first tried `=unique(query(data_table,"SELECT D, BY"))`

Then, I tried to surround it with single quotes `=unique(query(data_table,"SELECT D, 'BY'"))`

Comment: Yes.  I marked the question as answered way back when.  I redid the acceptance today.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Put BY column identifier between back quotes, `` =unique(query(data_table,"SELECT D, `BY`")) ``

## Explanation

BY is a Google Query Language keyword. From https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Identifiers

> #### Identifiers
>
> Identifiers (or IDs) are text strings that identify columns.
>
> Important: If your identifier
>
> - Has spaces,
> - Is a reserved word,
> - Contains anything but alphanumeric characters or underscores ([a-zA-Z0-9_]), or
> - Starts with a digit
>
> it *must* be surrounded by back-quotes (not single quotes).